# Jquery toggleClass for mulitiple buttons

Tags: php, jquery

The next button loops information coming from the database using PHP so I have multiple buttons. When I hover over the image, the button with the `view-data` class, will toggle the class `d-block`, but I want it to show only the next button, not all the buttons together. How can I do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".product-img").hover(function() {
    $(".view_data").toggleClass("d-block");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="product-img" style="width:100%;" />
<input type="button" name="view" value="Quick View" class="view_data">
```

Comment: did you place each set in `div`?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you don't need any JS/jQuery code. You can just use the `:hover` selector on the relevant `img` and button `input` elements to make the related siblings elements `display: block`. Try this:

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #F00;
  display: block;
}

input[type="button"] {
  display: none;
}

img:hover+input[type="button"],
input[type="button"]:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="product-img" />
<input type="button" name="view" value="Quick View" class="view_data">

<img class="product-img" />
<input type="button" name="view" value="Quick View" class="view_data">

<img class="product-img" />
<input type="button" name="view" value="Quick View" class="view_data">
```